# Deleting text in textarea makes element disappear

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've found a really weird bug on a site I'm working on where a `textarea` will disappear if I delete all the text from it - but only if that text was long enough to create a scroll bar. Deleting a small amount of text is fine. It also only seems to happen in Chrome on a Mac (although I haven't extensively browser tested yet).

I've recreated the bug in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/GgrrmG)*.

The bug has been recreated by pasting all the CSS properties currently being applied to my `textarea`. Now my problem is that there is over 260 CSS properties to check through to find out which one is causing it.

Is there anything I can do to debug this faster then going through all the CSS properties applied?

*For posterity's sake, here is the list of properties being applied to the `textarea`:

```
textarea{
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-clip-path: none;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-filter: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-locale: auto;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 131.671875px 45px;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-transform: none;
-webkit-transform-origin: 131.671875px 45px;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
align-content: stretch;
align-items: start;
align-self: start;
alignment-baseline: auto;
backface-visibility: visible;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-blend-mode: normal;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 100%);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: column;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: left;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: avenir, '“Helvetica Neue”', Arial, sans-serif;
font-kerning: auto;
font-size: 18px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 90px;
image-rendering: auto;
justify-content: flex-start;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: normal;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 5.359375px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 90px;
min-width: 0px;
object-fit: fill;
object-position: 50% 50%;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
paint-order: fill stroke markers;
perspective: none;
perspective-origin: 131.671875px 45px;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
resize: both;
right: auto;
shape-image-threshold: 0;
shape-margin: 0px;
shape-outside: none;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: start;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
touch-action: auto;
transform: none;
transform-origin: 131.671875px 45px;
transform-style: flat;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: top;
visibility: visible;
white-space: pre-wrap;
widows: auto;
width: 263.359375px;
will-change: auto;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
}
```

Update: CSS with inherited values omitted (however the bug doesn't seem to reproduce with just these properties).

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 100%);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
float: left;
font-family: avenir, '“Helvetica Neue”', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 90px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 5.359375px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
min-height: 90px;
outline-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
resize: both;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
vertical-align: top;
white-space: pre-wrap;
width: 263.359375px;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
```

Comment: can't reproduce on chrome. Also, most of those 'properties' are default values. Please post **your** properties.

Comment: Does it not occur when you delete the text in that codepen? I will update with the inherited values omitted, but the bug doesn't seem to occur when I do that.

Comment: This line looked problematic due to the nested curly quotes, though on reflection, while the curly quotes may prevent Helvetica Neue from being found, it doesn't fix the issue:

font-family: avenir, '“Helvetica Neue”', Arial, sans-serif;
Initially, removing these appeared to alter how the issue displayed, but further testing seems to indicate that this is something to do with inconsistencies in how the issue displays in codepen after saves and reloads of the page.

Comment: The key issue here is—this isn't the right way to use CSS. You need to build up the properties manually, to create the effect you want. If you did it that way, which is normal practice, you wouldn't have this issue. It seems highly improbable that that massive list of properties is required to achieve the effect you need. Start with a blank slate and add properties until you've got what you require.

Comment: @DuncanBabbage I have built this CSS manually, but this bug is only recently discovered so I'm not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have identified issue as being a bug in chrome.

For some reason, if a `textarea` element contains enough text that it requires an inner scrollbar, while at the same time having a "float" property. It will produce this problem, when the text in the textarea text is no longer long enough to need the scrollbar.

**As a simple solution, remove the float property from the `textarea`.**

I have replicated the issue in codepen: http://codepen.io/viralpickaxe/pen/VYPzgJ

I have submitted an issue on the chromium project issues page: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447421

Note:
I have tested this is multiple browsers and only seems to happen in chrome.

Comment: I reproduced the error in Safari for Mac OS X via your codepen yesterday, so perhaps it is a WebKit issue, as both browsers use WebKit for rendering.